# Hero image exclusively is being unresponsive

Tags: html, css

For some reason my hero image, and only my hero image isn't being responsive with the rest of the page.

My html is:

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=devicewidth, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>prototype</title>
    </head>
    <header>
<div class="hero">
            <img src="images/hero.jpg" alt="hero">
        </div>
```

And my css is for this is:

```
header {
    max-width: 1340px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

What should I do to make it responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want, this will make image responsive:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  }
.hero {
  max-width: 1340px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```